# CCAvenue Payment Gateway Responce Message Return 404 error

Tags: payment-gateway, magento1.9.2.3

After successfully integrated CCAvenue Payment gateway response message return 404 error,

Form :

```
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="hidden" name="tid" id="tid" readonly />
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="1234"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="123654789"/>

                <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="INR"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="abc.com/ccavResponseHandler.php"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="abc.com/ccavResponseHandler.php"/>
                <inputtype="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="pass">Pay</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your redirect url and cancel url is not support in magento. Check those are wrong.

Comment: I am using ccavenue, their docs also said same,  CCAvenue  -> http://localhost/ccavResponseHandler.php

Comment: the doc is for custom php but in magento you have to follow magento architecture.

Comment: No i am also using custom PHP, not magento

Comment: CCAVENUE form : https://paste.ofcode.org/ea7AZYgCPCevVLmR82hAxa

Comment: Then can not help you with out debug your code